# Open Unity or C# project using python on a MacOS?

Tags: python, c#, macos, unity-game-engine

How do you open a Unity/C# project using python code (pycharm)?

I have a unity app and I am writing a script to open the app in the background and sign it. I've completed this task for Windows but the same code doesn't work for Mac, as expected.

Even if I change the paths, I keep facing 2 errors, (1) file/folder not found & (2) not enough permission.

So how could I open a project in Unity or a C# solution in my python code for MacOs?

I can open Unity using:

```
UNITY = ["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "Unity.app"]
subprocess.run(f'{UNITY} -projectPath /Users/graphic/Documents/GitHub/proj')
```

On windows, all runs well using:

```
subprocess.run(
    f'{UNITY} -quit -projectPath C:\\Project\\Location -batchmode  -executeMethod BuildScript.BuildAll')
```

Comment: By open the project .. do you actually mean in the Unity Editor or a built version of it?

Comment: The end state would be a built Mac standalone. So right now, I’m trying to figure out how to access the project within my Python code.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, the actual executable file is inside the Unity.app directory (an .app file is really a folder).
The right path may be something like `/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.1.28f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity`, depending on which version you installed and where you let the Hub install it, or where you installed it yourself.

I don't know how it works in combination with Python but I suspect you should set your `{UNITY}` variable to a path like my example path.

Comment: I can get Unity to open by using `subprocess.run(UNITY)` but the problem is opening the project will not open. So the challenge is opening the project in either Unity or a C# IDE (example: vs). So I suspect the error must be at `-projectPath /Path/To/Project/Folder`

Comment: If I set the UNITY variable to your example, ending the path with `.app`, I also get "permission denied". But when I fix the path to the actual executable inside the `.app` directory,  I get no errors, running a similar build command on a project I have here. Unity running in batchmode will not open any windows so you won't see that it's running just like that.